# Can I use Django's administration interface with a non-sql database?

Tags: django, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm hoping to use Amazon's dynamoDB with a Django application. I know that the administration interface is relying on a relational DB like MySql or SqlLite. Can I use the administration interface on a non-relational DB such as dynamoDB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is http://django-nonrel.org/. But that only supports MongoDB & Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

A Django session backend for DynamoDB

https://github.com/gtaylor/django-dynamodb-sessions